# Using pct_change with multiindex groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use pct_change on the result of a groupby in order to calculate the period to period change in value across many different items.

My data is structured like this:

```
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.array([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]),np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'])]
s = pd.Series(np.array([100,101,102,103,200,201,202,203]), index=arrays)
s.name='values'
df = pd.DataFrame(s, index=arrays).sort_index()
df.index.names =['day','symbol']
```

I need to calculate the percent change of each symbol for each day.  When I run something like this:

```
df.groupby(level='symbol').values.diff()
```

I get the correct output.  But when I run this:

```
df.groupby(level='symbol').values.pct_change()
```

it returns the wrong result (compares bar to foo)

I can get what I'm looking for either by wrapping in a lambda like this:

```
my_func = lambda x: x.pct_change()
df.groupby(level='symbol').values.apply(my_func)
```

or by doing this:

```
df.groupby(level='symbol').values.diff() / df.groupby(level='symbol').values.shift(1)
```

so I'm really just trying to understand the reason for the difference in behavior of pct_change vs. other pandas methods.

Comment: This is interesting.  Wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: @ScottBoston, it looks like a bug to me...

Answer (score 3):

For multi-index dataframes on pandas 0.24.2 this solution worked for me:

```
pd.__version__

'0.24.2'


df.groupby(level='symbol')['values'].pct_change()


    day  symbol
1    bar            NaN
     foo            NaN
2    bar       0.010000
     foo       0.005000
3    bar       0.009901
     foo       0.004975
4    bar       0.009804
     foo       0.004950
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we have to use `.apply()` in order to use it with the multi-index DF:

```
In [61]: df.groupby(level='symbol')['values'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
Out[61]:
day  symbol
1    bar            NaN
     foo            NaN
2    bar       0.010000
     foo       0.005000
3    bar       0.009901
     foo       0.004975
4    bar       0.009804
     foo       0.004950
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

PS this looks like a bug to me - IMO it won't work properly when grouping by one of multi-index level:

```
In [101]: g = df.groupby(level='symbol')

In [102]: g.values.pct_change??
Signature: g.values.pct_change(periods=1, fill_method='pad', limit=None, freq=None)
Source:
    def pct_change(self, periods=1, fill_method='pad', limit=None, freq=None):
        """Calculate percent change of each value to previous entry in group"""
        filled = getattr(self, fill_method)(limit=limit)
        shifted = filled.shift(periods=periods, freq=freq)

        return (filled / shifted) - 1
File:      c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py
Type:      method
```

---

reproducing the code:

```
In [103]: filled = g['values'].pad(limit=None)

In [104]: shifted = filled.shift(periods=1, freq=None)

In [105]: (filled / shifted) - 1
Out[105]:
day  symbol
1    bar            NaN
     foo       1.000000
2    bar      -0.495000
     foo       0.990099
3    bar      -0.492537
     foo       0.980392
4    bar      -0.490099
     foo       0.970874
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

I'd recommend to check whether such issue already exist on [Pandas-Issues](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) and open a new one if it doesn't exist yet...